# Why can't I open DLL file? Every time it returns NULL

Tags: c++, dll, windows-api-code-pack

So, I'm trying to use a function from DLL file and for some reason I can't open the DLL file: when I'm using the `LoadLibrary` function it returns as `NULL`
I'm freaking out that I can't find this bug

```
typedef unsigned int (WINAPI* AvVersion)(void);
void secret()
{
    HMODULE dll = LoadLibrary("Secret.dll");

    if (dll == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "coudlnt open ""secret.dll""\nError Code:" << GetLastError() << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    AvVersion function = (AvVersion)GetProcAddress(dll, "TheAnswerToLifeTheUniverseAndEverything");
    std::cout << "result:" << function() << std::endl;
}
```

The code number is 126
and the name of the function is `TheAnswerToLifeTheUniverseAndEverything`

Comment: Where is the dll? Is it in the working directory?

Comment: @tkausl yes  it is

Comment: So what did your code print out ? the value GetLastError() should tell why LoadLibrary() fails.

Comment: Yes, what's the error code? You took the time to create a question on Stackoverflow but you didn't check the error code? I bet that it's "file not found".

Comment: I searched on the MSDN and it says  " The specified module could not be found.
"

Comment: @BJovke yes it is

Comment: its in the directory https://ibb.co/n6rdTc

Comment: It has to be in the same directory as your .EXE or in the directory you're starting your EXE from, not in this one.

Comment: Or in path, system32, etc. There's a MSDN doc stating in which order the DLL is being searched for.

Comment: still not working :|

Comment: Does it matter that I use visual studio?

Comment: Are you launching your program from Visual studio IDE? If yes then working directory is up one level from the one in your picture, copy the DLL there.

Comment: well, it still not working

Comment: I copy the dll to the upper directory where the solution is

Comment: `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND` does not mean the DLL itself is not found.  It means the DLL is found, but one of its dependent DLLs is not being found.  Subtle but important difference. If your DLL has dependencies, make sure they are all in the same folder, or on the system search path.

Comment: Copy the DLL to the same directory where your EXE is. Then open command prompt, CHDIR to that directory and start the application. If this doesn't work then DLL's dependencies are not met or you have a mismatch between the DLL and your app. For example, DLL is 32 bit and app 64 bit, DLL is in debug version and app in release (this is rare), etc.